# apache keeps old .htaccess settings (in rewriterule)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am testing some basic .htaccess rewriterules and I am pretty sure that even after deleting a rule in .htaccess and saving the document, apache ignores it and acts like the rule was still there (only for earlier requested sites) - even after apache restart. It is driving me crazy, the behavior is really mad. Is there any apache cache which is about to be cleaned or the problem is elsewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It's madness! Not really, it's just annoying.**

When you set a redirect in Apache what you're doing is actually configuring headers that are passed to your browser. [Your browser keeps a cache of 301 and 302 redirect headers](http://getluky.net/2010/12/14/301-redirects-cannot-be-undon/) (and other things like DNS) in the event you go back to those pages, so it can save you time. 301 redirects are supposed to be permanent (that's what you're indicating), so if there is no need for the browser to do something like perform a DNS lookup or visit a page based on a redirect, then it will cut corners and use the cache in order to provide you with a faster browsing experience.

You need to flush your browser's cache to prevent the store redirects from happening.

Additionally, you'll want to resubmit your page to Google (in the event it's on the web) in case they've crawled your site while the invalid headers existed.

Comment: Thanks, but even after complete cache flush it works strange. In my .htaccess file (in `/folder1/folder2`) I have a line `RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /folder1/folder2/?pg=$1 [L,QSA,R=302]` and if I type `localhost/folder1/folder2/page/` I obtain `?pg=page.php` with that `.php` I have absolutely no clue why...